# Changing volume at command line using script/function

Tags: terminal, applescript, bash

I found this nifty command which sets volume to 50% (or any level desired):

```
osascript -e 'set volume output volume 50'
```

I'd love to have a script or function that lets me type `v 50` or `v 30`, etc. to easily change the volume levels.

I tried making this bash function:

```
v() {
# adjust volume function
osascript -e 'set volume output volume $1'
}
```

However this gives:

```
25:26: syntax error: Expected expression but found unknown token. (-2741)
```

How can I make this work?

Comment: As a side note: to mute the volume, use `osascript -e 'set volume output muted true'`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Single quotes ('') suppress parameter expansion so you have to use double quotes:

```
v() {
    osascript -e "set volume output $1"
}
```

Comment: Excellent - that works, thank you. More generally - when should one use double versus single quotes?

Comment: Single quotes protect everything within, so use double quotes whenever you need to expand variables etc.